Thurston's metric on $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ is twisted. So is this paper "wrong"?
$\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ is the universal covering space of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, the group of $2\times 2$ real matrices with determinant $1$. This group acts via Möbius transformations on the upper half-plane model of hyperbolic geometry, namely by
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\ c& d\end{bmatrix}\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})\sim f_A(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}.$$
By Iwasawa decomposition, every element of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ writes as
$$\tag{1}\begin{bmatrix}1&x\\ 0& 1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{y}&0\\ 0& \sqrt{y}^{-1}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta\\ \sin \theta& \cos\theta\end{bmatrix},$$
for some $x,y,\theta\in \mathbb{R}$, $y>0$. This decomposition is unique up to $\theta$'s ambiguity. Actually, this shows exactly that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is given by $\mathbb{H}^2\times \mathbb{S}^1$ as differential manifolds and therefore it is not simply connected. That's why we consider $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ if we want the Thurston's model geometry.
Consider $\Upsilon:\mathbb{H}^2\times \mathbb{R}\to SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ defining $\Upsilon(x,y,\theta)$ by (1). One can verify this is a covering map. Imposing that $\{\Upsilon_x,\Upsilon_y,\Upsilon_\theta\}$ is orthonormal at $\Upsilon(0,1,0)$ (namely, the identity of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ ) then extending this to an orthonormal frame on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ by left translations, we get a left-invariant riemannian metric on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ -  as we usually do with Lie groups.
Then, we can induce a riemannian metric on the covering space $\mathbb{H}^2\times \mathbb{R}$, simply by putting
$$\langle \partial_i,\partial_j\rangle_{(x,y,\theta)} = \langle \partial_i\Upsilon(x,y,\theta),\partial_j\Upsilon(x,y,\theta) \rangle_{\Upsilon(x,y,\theta)}. $$
After some computation I've found the following metric on $\mathbb{H}^2\times \mathbb{R}=\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$:
$$g(\partial_i,\partial_j)=\begin{bmatrix}
\dfrac{1+\sin^4\theta}{y^2}&\dfrac{\cos\theta \sin^3\theta}{y^2} & \dfrac{-\sin^2\theta}{y}\\
\dfrac{\cos\theta \sin^3\theta}{y^2}& \dfrac{1+\cos^2\theta \sin^2\theta}{y^2} & \dfrac{-\cos\theta \sin\theta}{y}\\
\dfrac{-\sin^2\theta}{y}&\dfrac{-\cos\theta \sin\theta}{y} & 1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Of course, the indexes $1,2,3$ are associated with parameters $x,y,\theta$.
The computations are tedious, so hopefully I didn't do any mistakes.
Now notice how the metric is twisted. For $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ the metric coincides with the half-plane model on the respective slice. I believe this (up to some mistake on the computations) would be Thurston's model. Can anyone confirm?

BUT what if we extended the orthonormal frame on $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ by right translations (getting then a right-invariant metric) instead of left ones?

I also did this and then induced the metric on $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$. This time I've got
$$g(\partial_i,\partial_j)=\begin{bmatrix}
1&\dfrac{-x}{y} & \dfrac{1-x^2-y^2}{y}\\
\dfrac{-x}{y}& \dfrac{1+x^2}{y^2} & \dfrac{x(x^2+y^2+1)}{y}\\
\dfrac{1-x^2-y^2}{y}&\dfrac{x(x^2+y^2+1)}{y^2} & \dfrac{(x^2+y^2)^2+2(x^2-y^2+1)}{y^2}
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Not twisted this time and therefore ''much simpler'' to find geodesics for example. However, the metric doesn't fit with hyperbolic one, on whatever slice we take. Actually, the metric doesn't depend on the fiber parameter so we have simply a product metric (please tell me if I'm wrong!).

So, this shows that we need to be careful about the choice of left or right action of the group.
Finally, I bring this article into discussion: Geodesics and geodesic spheres in $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ geometry.
Authors build a model using a hyperboloid in the projective space and collineation groups, which I'm not very familiar to, so that motivated me trying to find an alternative. By trying to do this (as I exposed above) I came upon an uncomfortable situation.
Take a look at (8) in the article, the metric tensor matrix. It is not twisted! I mean, the matrix doesn't depend on the fiber parameter. As long as I understood the paper, authors claim to have exhibited all the geodesics and even spheres of small radius... In my twisted model though this is nearly impossible!

But the metric on Thurston's $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$ should be twisted, right? So is this paper just wrong or am I missing something?

I'm just looking for a concrete model for Thurston's $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$, i.e. an $\mathbb{R}^3$ open set endowed with a Riemannian metric. I would appreciate references!

After taking a carefull read in P. Scott's The Geometries of 3-manifolds, I'm posting a (partial) answer myself.
Basically, I just misunderstood concepts. Many sources call Thurston's model geometries given by $Nil_3$, $Sol$ and $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R}})$ the "twisted" ones.
Then, I just mistakenly took this term as meaning "a metric that depends on the fiber parameter" (kind of warped metric).
I see this certainly is not the case after reading Scott. Here's why: after all the construction (which is not the same I proposed), translations along the fibers must be isometries! Which means in particular that slices (given by fixing a fiber parameter) are isometric. This can't be the case if the metric depended on the fiber parameter.
The article I meantioned follows a construction given by E. Molnár in The projective interpretation of the eight 3-dimensional homogeneous geometries and seems to be just fine.

The thing that it's not clear to me yet is, why are these geometries called "twisted"?


I think the "twisted" name comes from what happens if you lift a smooth oriented loop in $\mathbb{H}^2$ up to $\widetilde{SL(2,\mathbb{R})}$. If the lift is point wise orthogonal to the fibers of this loop, then it will not return to it's starting point, in contrast to what happens when you lift to $\mathbb{H}^2\times S^1$. This is described in the notes Geometric Structures of 3-manifolds by Bonahon, available here.
